# Icinga2 permissions for all LDAP users

Tags: icinga

I have a Icinga2 running with *Active Directory* as authentication backend and *Icinga Web 2* as frontend.

The frontend permissions can be configured using the `roles.ini` in Icingaweb2's config folder. This is what I have in there:

```
# roles.ini

[Users]
users = "*"
permissions = "module/monitoring"
```

As you can see, I want to give *all* authenticated users access to the *monitoring* module. I have no group, which contains all users so I cannot use a group for that.

This does not work. How is the correct syntax to give the permission to all users?

(Of course, using existing user names or group names *does* work, backend configuration therefore is correct.) Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Since the roles are bound to users/usergroups I would go that route of adding new users to a default group by default. Similar to what's described in the documentation: https://github.com/Icinga/icingaweb2/blob/master/doc/06-Security.md#roles In case you may convince the developers by adding a feature request for wildcard user matches - hop onto dev.icinga.org :)

Comment: I have the same problem and no solution so far. Auth via Apache+LDAP and than "no permission" because Icingaweb2 can not handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature was implemented in IcingaWeb2 version 2.5, see https://github.com/Icinga/icingaweb2/pull/3096. It's a very simple patch against `AdmissionLoader.php`, which you can also apply separately by hand:

```
commit f495b390da6eb257ca101889deb70ccc22bb99c7
Author: Eric Lippmann <eric.lippmann@icinga.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 16 12:01:06 2017 +0100

    Apply role to all users if the role is defined with users=*

    If the users directive contains at least one single asterisk, the role is applied to all users.
    So, this supports roles which define users=username, ..., * and users=*

    refs #3095

diff --git a/library/Icinga/Authentication/AdmissionLoader.php b/library/Icinga/Authentication/AdmissionLoader.php
index 0a80be127..8ee43dbfb 100644
--- a/library/Icinga/Authentication/AdmissionLoader.php
+++ b/library/Icinga/Authentication/AdmissionLoader.php
@@ -28,6 +28,9 @@ class AdmissionLoader
         $username = strtolower($username);
         if (! empty($section->users)) {
             $users = array_map('strtolower', StringHelper::trimSplit($section->users));
+            if (in_array('*', $users)) {
+                return true;
+            }
             if (in_array($username, $users)) {
                 return true;
             }
```